# What is the difference between close billing account and disable billing account in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the difference between close billing account and disable billing account in Google Cloud Platform?

If I have a project with Vm running and other resources, what happens if I close the billing account and disable the billing account?

Answer (score 2):

If you disable billing, no more automatic payments are charged, but you are still responsible to pay for any outstanding costs you might have.

If you close the billing account, all billable services will be stopped automatically.

As per the [google cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project):

> If you disable billing for a project, some of your Google Cloud resources might be removed and become non-recoverable. Instead, consider shutting down your project. Shutting down a project releases all resources used within the project.

Comment: So if I disable billing, the VM will be stopped and removed by Google automatically ?
And if I close the billing, the VM will be stopped but not removed?

Comment: Correct. Services can be restored once billing is opened again.